# Assigning 1 CPU to do 1 Thread

Tags: cpu, threading

I am implementing a code that create a pulse output via a digital IO for stepper driver.
However i notice when there is a 'stray' program running (ie anti virus), the output(duty cycle) will become inconsistent. 
Is there anyway to assign that thread to 1 single CPU in multi-core CPUs so that other programs even windows managed cannot assign thread to that CPU?
I am using C# as programming.

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: I am using win10 64 bits x64 Processor

Comment: I am honest to say you will be more successful if you turned to Linux.

Comment: @harogaston Linux is similarly not suitable for this kind of task. You'd need either a proper RTOS or just the raw program without any OS if you want any kind of guarantee.

Comment: @Bob I strongly disagree. Linux is WAY more suitable for this kind of thing than Windows. Go tell Windows how to assign CPU priority for interrupts, or for user land processes. Good luck with that! This does not mean that a real time OS is better, of course it is, for instance RT Linux. But there is no discussion that if you plan on tinkering with the kernel then you will feel way more at home on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this would be to enumerate every other process in the system and set its affinity mask to exclude the CPU you're trying to save for your thread. You'll have to keep doing this, too, as additional processes may be created at any time.

A better approach is to simply run your process in the "real time" priority class and then set your thread priority to "time critical". (I hope it doesn't have to be actually executing at too high a percentage of the total time.)

However, interrupt handlers and DPC routines will still be able to interfere with your thread.

Your real problem here is that Windows is not intended for nor suited for tasks with "hard" real-time requirements, and yours sounds like that.

I suggest using a microcontroller that's dedicated to generating the variable-duty-cycle pulses your stepper motor needs.

What is the range of frequency and duty cycle the stepper motor needs? There may be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you make the sound card or serial port somehow generate the duty cycle?

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about the sound card. Generate wav data of square waves with the duty cycle you need (a trivial calculation) and call WaveOut.

Comment: The minimum for the driver is 400Pulse/Rev which i need for constant speed and position accuracy. Also i am using a Single board computer so sound card is kinda out for me.